# How to get only 3 string after @ from @get.com or @getting.com in VBA

Tags: vba, substring, instr

How to get only 3 string after @ from @get.com or @getting.com in VBA 
for example i have to achieve @get from provided string @get.com or @getting.com

Comment: E.g. try `mid$("Something@getting.com",instr(1,"Something@getting.com","@"),4)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Instr()` function to locate the @ in your string.

Then use `Mid()` to substring *n* chars starting from this location